# Django-SEO giving error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, meta-tags

I am trying to implement meta tags in an existing Django app. For this, am using [Redsolution Django-SEO](https://github.com/redsolution/django-seo)

As they showed in the readme, my setup and migrations are all fine. Even the fields are appearing in the admin properly. However, in the template I am following their convention and putting this in the `head` section:

```
{% load seo_tags %} 
<meta name="description" content="{% seo description for article %}">
<meta name="keywords" content="{% seo keywords for article %}">
```

The load part is not causing any error, however the following lines throw the following error in the debug mode:

> NameError at /articles/columnjp/podcast-test/

followed by:

> global name 'seo' is not defined

I am wondering what this syntax is, in the first place:

```
{% seo description for article %}
```

Is this a standard syntax component or something custom to this module ? What changes should I make to fix this error ? If any other information or code-component is required, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "fetch and output" part of this plugin has bugs or incompatibility with newer versions of Django (in my case 1.6).

Anyways, I have studied the code in this library and written my own for this part and it works. For anyone stuck in a similar situation, I am posting my implementation for reference. The code below is in my views for the target sub-part (app) of the project which needed this plugin:

```
from seo.models import Seo

def get_keywords(self, article):    
    seo_object = Seo.objects.get(object_id=article.id)
    keywords = seo_object.keywords
    return keywords

def get_description(self, article): 
    seo_object = Seo.objects.get(object_id=article.id)
    description = seo_object.description
    return description
```

I am not using titles, but similar concept can be used for them too. After this, am passing the returned values in *context* to the *template* HAML/HTML and then in the head part, using that to create markup for the meta-data.

By this fix, this plugin's flawless integration from the admin and binding ability to models can still be used.